# Selector for React-Redux

Tags: react-redux

To use selector, I tried to follow this URL reference: https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/

One of the example is :

```js
const selectSomeData = state => state.someData;

const selectFilteredSortedTransformedData = createSelector(
  selectSomeData,
  (someData) => {
    const filteredData = expensiveFiltering(someData);
    const sortedData = expensiveSorting(filteredData);
    const transformedData = expensiveTransformation(sortedData);

    return transformedData;
  }
)

const mapState = (state) => {
  const transformedData = selectFilteredSortedTransformedData(state);

  return {
    data: transformedData
  };
}
```

**Question:** Within mapState we are calling selectFilteredSortedTransformedData and we are also passing State as parameter. However, the function itself is not taking any parameter, how does it work?

```
const selectFilteredSortedTransformedData = createSelector(
```

Answer (score 0):

did you add mapState function in redux connect function ?? something like this.

export default connect(mapState)(Component)

Comment: Yes, but that's not my question here.